# Level sets and Concave function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, economics

in my Calculus textbook about Concave functions the following is derived from this expression:

Let $f$ be a function defined in a convex set which is subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $Df(x)$ the first derivative gradient of this function.

$f$ is concave iff for every $x,y$ belonging to $U.$
$$f(y)-f(x)< Df(x)(y-x)$$

and from this expression the author somehow concluded that:

Given that the gradient is perpendicular to the tangent plane of the level set of $f(x)$ in a given $x$ if $f(x)$ is concave then all the level set which satisfied ($z$ given that $f(z)\geq f(x)$) are above the tangent plane where above means in the direction of the increasing values of $f$. Also it has this figure:

[image: Extracted from simon and blume: mathematics for economists]

Can someone explain me how to conclude this from the above definition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: @Mikal Simon's and Blume's Mathematics for Economists, Chap 21 Pag 513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle is that for vectors,
$$
cos(\theta) = \dfrac{x \cdot y}{||x|| * ||y||}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$.  If $x$ and $y$ make an acute angle, then $\dfrac{x \cdot y}{||x|| * ||y||} \ge 0$.

For a concave function, suppose $f(z) \ge f(x)$ like you say.  Then
$$
\dfrac{\nabla f(x) \cdot (z-x)}{||\nabla f(x)||*||z-x||} \ge \dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||*||z-x||}\ge 0
$$
so that for any vector $z$ that improves $f$, the gradient and $z-x$ form an acute angle.

More generally, quasi-concave functions have the property that $f$ is quasi-concave iff $f(z)\ge f(x)$ implies $ \nabla f(x) \cdot (z-x) \ge 0$, which is more obviously related to the geometry of the situation. The gradient always makes an acute angle with vectors that improve the objective, and is orthogonal to the supporting hyperplane to the indifference curve.  Concave functions are quasi-concave, since the other definition of quasi-concave is that $f$ is quasi-concave iff $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \ge \min\{f(x),f(y)\}$ for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$, which gives a lot of intuition about how the upper contour sets and gradients behave.  It is also an ordinal, and not cardinal property, like concavity.

I like de la Fuente's or Ok's math econ books much better.  Simon and Blume is somehow very encyclopedic without being very precise.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand it better. I'm taking my first introductory course to RA, can you give me some advice? Apart from the bibliography you already mentioned.

Comment: Real analysis and you're reading Simon and Blume?  Huh.  I took an "Intro to RA" class like 20 years ago with Bartle and Sherbert, then an RA class with Rudin (I also read Royden and really liked it); that used to be the industry standard, but I don't know what it is today.  There are lots of great books once you are past that stage. One of my favorites is Dudley's "RA and Probability".  It all depends where you see yourself going with math.  For econ and if you just had multivariate calc, I would read Bartle and Sherbert, then Varian, and if that all goes well, MWG and maybe Luenberger red.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: In my original post I completely misunderstood what was being asked.

Define the set
$$S = \{x: f(x) \geq \alpha\}$$

where $f \in C^1$ is concave. Can we use the concavity and differentiability of $f$ to know what $S$ looks like without solving the problem analytically?

Let's first try to find an inner box. We locate points $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p$ for which $f(x_i) = \alpha$. Using the concavity of $f$, the set $S$ must surely contain all elements on the lines between these vertices, i.e. $S$ must contain the inner box defined by the vertices $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p$.

It seems (to me) that the original authors wish to point out that we can use the differentiability of the function $f$ to make an outer box of the set using the tangent hyperplanes defined by the gradients at $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p$. Further if we let $p \rightarrow \infty$ then we have $S$ exactly.

In the following illustration I show what such an inner box and outer box look like for $p=4$.

[image: Inner and outer box of level set]

I hope this made more sense than my original answer.

Comment: Although I get your point, I don't realize how your answer is related to the authors statement.Furthermore, how your explanation is related with the tangent plane and the gradient vector?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I've corrected my answer to (as far as I can) explain what I think the authors intended to illustrate.